# Gnuplot script file not working under Windows when plotting single points

Tags: windows, echo, gnuplot, xubuntu

I am a bit confused, I have the same gnuplot script that works under

Version 4.6 patchlevel 4 Build System: Linux x86_64

but not under

Version 4.6 patchlevel 5 Build System: MS-Windows 32 bit

the script file is

```
clear

set terminal epslatex size 20cm,14cm
set output 'mwe.tex'

set style data points

set style line 101 lc rgb "black" lw 2 pt 1 ps 2

set grid

set xlabel 'xlabel'
set ylabel 'ylabel'
xmin=  -0.2
xmax=  0.7
set xrange [xmin:xmax]


set key below

plot "<echo '0.408 270.7'" with points ls 101 notitle,\
```

Does the command `"<echo` somehow not work under Windows?

The error I get with Windows is  'skipping unreadable file "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<` pipes the following command through a shell (see `help special-filenames`). The command itself is mostly system-dependent and not part of gnuplot (in this case the `echo`).

If you want a portable way to specify a single point, you can set an empty label and use the `point` option:

```
set style line 101 lc rgb "black" lw 2 pt 1 ps 2
set label at 0.408, 270.7 "" point ls 101
```

Note, that this works only if you also plot other stuff, since the label is set only if the `plot` command is invoked.

Comment: Thanks! (it only needs a comma between the coordinates but I could not edit your post, it asked for 6 characters minumum)

Answer (score 1):

`echo` (lower case) is a unix command. In windows you will need to use `"<ECHO` in uppercase.

Comment: I got the same error changing the case, but the solution below by Christoph worked for me. Will keep that in mind though, thanks!

Comment: The case doesn't matter on Windows, but ssing pipes as such on Windows seems not to be so straightforward. First, you must use the `wgnuplot_pipes` executable, and you must omit the internal quotes. Then the following works fine: `plot "< echo 0.408 270.7" w p ls 101`.